# HTML layer over YouTube player

Tags: flash, dhtml

Anyone here have success with layering HTML content on top of the YouTube player embedded using swfobject (v1.5 or 2.0)?

I'm able to layer HTML over flash in other areas of the site. Problem is specific to YouTube's player and IE6/7.

I'm using absolute positioning and z-index on the HTML layer.

I'm passing wmode=transparent in as a param to flash

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always",wmode: "transparent" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/ID_OF_VIDEO&amp;border=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer","ytapiplayer", "426", "357", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

UPDATE: So it turns out that the absolute positioning of the youtube container was preventing the html layer from coming to the front. I have wmode set to 'transparent' and it's working in all browsers. Thanks for the suggestions below

Answer (score 3):

You need to set **wmode** to **opaque** and it should work. I had the same problem today, so I'm posting my sollution here (tested in Firefox, IE6, IE7).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last year and solved it by using the 'normal' embed generated by CS3, I suggest you give it a try (at least for debugging purposes).